# Why uint64_t cannot show pow(2, 64) - 1 properly?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, uint64

I'm trying to understand why `uint64_t` type can not show `pow(2,64)-1`  properly. The  cplusplus standard is 199711L.

I checked the `pow()` function under C++98 standard which is

```
double pow (double base     , double exponent);
float pow (float base      , float exponent);
long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);
double pow (double base     , int exponent);
long double pow (long double base, int exponent);
```

So I wrote the following snippet

```
double max1 = (pow(2, 64) - 1);
cout << max1 << endl;

uint64_t max2 = (pow(2, 64) - 1);
cout << max2 << endl;

uint64_t max3 = -1;
cout << max3 << endl;
```

The outputs are:

```
max1: 1.84467e+019
max2: 9223372036854775808
max3: 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e

Comment: To compute 2^64 - 1, 2^64 must fit in a register before subtracting 1. Granted, the result fits in a uint64_t, but not the intermediate result.

Comment: @AlexG, Thanks. I thought it is the case. However, it can not explain why   
  double max1 = (pow(2, 64) - 1); shows correctly.

Comment: Are you certain it does use the integer version of the pow function?

Comment: One thing to be noted: IEEE 754 (which double *usually* follows) defines 52 bit for the mantissa - which limits double's precision (in normalized mode, you have one *implicit* bit more, but still). So you won't ever be able to represent `2^64-1` correctly in double either, but actually suffer from rounding.

Comment: I can't get this to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/sz5atd

Comment: @Diame `double` doesn't, but you aren't checking down to the digits that are wrong

Comment: @Justin you lack `#include <cmath>` and (possibly) `std::` from the call site

Comment: @Caleth No, I declared the functions. I could've renamed it to `foo(...)`. I was just showing that the stated overload set can't compile with the given expression. It probably would have made more sense to do it that way, though.

Comment: `uint64_t max2b = pow(2.0, 64.0) - 2048.0;` will do closer to what you want, since 2048.0 is epsilon at that range.  (Assuming IEEE 754.)

Comment: Take note that `2^64-1 == uint64_t(-1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point numbers have finite precision.

On your system (and typically, assuming binary64 IEEE-754 format) `18446744073709551615` is not a number that has a representation in the `double` format. The closest number that does have a representation happens to be `18446744073709551616`.

Subtracting (and adding) together two floating point numbers of wildly different magnitudes usually produces an error. This error can be significant in relation to the smaller operand. In the case of `18446744073709551616. - 1. -> 18446744073709551616.` the error of the subtraction is 1, which is in fact the same value as the smaller operand.

When a floating point value is converted to an integer type, and the  value cannot fit in the integer type, the behaviour of the program is undefined - even when the integer type is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: It's **not** that *`uint64_t` type cannot show `pow(2,64)-1` properly* but the reverse: **`double` can't store precisely 2<sup>64</sup> - 1** due to the lack of significand bits. You can only do that with types with 64 bits of precision or more (like `long double` on many platforms). Try `std::pow(2.0L, 64) - 1.0L` (note the `L` suffix) or `powl(2.0L, 64) - 1.0L;` and see

Anyway you **shouldn't use a floating-point type for integer math** right from the beginning. Not only it's far slower to calculate `pow(2, x)` than `1ULL << x`, it'll also cause the issue you saw due to the limited precision of `double`. Use `uint64_t max2 = -1` instead, or `((unsigned __int128)1ULL << 64) - 1` if the compiler supports `__int128`

---

**`pow(2, 64) - 1` is a `double` expression**, ***not*** `int`, as `pow` doesn't have any overload that returns an integral type. The integer `1` will be promoted to the same rank as the result of `pow`

However because IEEE-754 double precision is only 64-bit long, you can **never** store values that have 64 significant bits or more like 2<sup>64</sup>-1

- [64-bit unsigned integers which cannot map onto a double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17782425/995714)
- [Are all integer values perfectly represented as doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43655668/995714)

So `pow(2, 64) - 1` will be rounded to the *closest representable value*, which is `pow(2, 64)` itself, and `pow(2, 64) - 1 == pow(2, 64)` will result in 1. The largest value that's smaller than it is 18446744073709549568 = 2<sup>64</sup> - 2048. You can check that with [`std::nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter)

On some platforms (notably x86, except on MSVC) **[`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) does have [64 bits of significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format)**, so you'll get the correct value in that case. The [following snippet](https://ideone.com/5W1YQ1)

```
double max1 = pow(2, 64) - 1;
std::cout << "pow(2, 64) - 1 = " << std::fixed << max1 << '\n';
std::cout << "Previous representable value: " << std::nextafter(max1, 0) << '\n';
std::cout << (pow(2, 64) - 1 == pow(2, 64)) << '\n';

long double max2 = pow(2.0L, 64) - 1.0L;
std::cout << std::fixed << max2 << '\n';
```

prints out

```
pow(2, 64) - 1 = 18446744073709551616.000000
Previous representable value: 18446744073709549568.000000
1
18446744073709551615.000000
```

You can clearly see `long double` can store the correct value as expected

On many other platforms `double` may be [IEEE-754 quadruple-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) or [double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_(arithmetic)). Both have more than 64 bits of significand so you can do the same thing. But of course the overhead will be higher